# How to install GTK+ "clearlooks" and "murrine" to fix this problem on Ubuntu with MATE?

Tags: 11.10, gtk, mate

[image]

This message says that the theme will not work correctly until I install the GTK+ "Clearlooks"

[image]

And this another message says that the theme will not work correctly until I install the GTK+ "Murrine"

And the same happen when I try GTK+ "smooth" themes

How to fix this problem?

OBS. : I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with MATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As most people may already know Mate is a port of the old Gnome 2.3xx series of desktops. As such it still relies on a lot of gtk-2 libraries. However work is on going to get gtk-3 working under the Mate desktop. And here in lays the problem because now the gtk themes folder has been moved. Because the older packages were not updated to reflect this change you  get a breakage of sorts.  There is a work around, But I don't know how long it will continue to work, and it varies depending on whether you have a 32 or 64 bit system. So I will try to help here, But this is not for the faint of heart as you need root privileges to make any of these changes. So caution is necessary as a mistake could render a system unstable or unusable. So if you are comfortable with root then here goes:

on a 32 bit system:
open a terminal and type: sudo caja
enter your password when ask, now you should have caja running in root mode.
Go to View and click Extra Pane, caja should now show a split file manager  allowing you to view two different folders at once. 
In one pane navigate to /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines 
In the other pane navigate to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines 
In the pane showing  /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines  select all of the files right click and select copy from the menu.
In the pane showing  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines right click and select paste from the menu. Skip any duplicates that may show up. 
Close caja and close the terminal, your themes should now work as intended.

on a 64 bit system:
open a terminal and type: sudo caja
enter your password when ask, now you should have caja running in root mode.
Go to View and click Extra Pane, caja should now show a split file manager  allowing you to view two different folders at once. 
In one pane navigate to /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines 
In the other pane navigate to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines 
In the pane showing  /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines  select all of the files right click and select copy from the menu.
In the pane showing /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines right click and select paste from the menu. Skip any duplicates that may show up. 
Close caja and close the terminal, your themes should now work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Clearlooks and Murrine are themes made in GTK2, and hasn't been ported to GTK3, so that's the reason you see those errors.

You could try to install GTK2 engine, to see if that gets your theme working, but i'm not even sure if this is possible.

There's also a theme GTK3 called Newlooks have you tried it?

Comment: I already had installed this package, but it did not fixed the problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: Install through Gnome Look site

Answer (score 0):

> Clearlooks and Murrine are themes made in GTK2, and hasn't been ported to GTK3, so that's the reason you see those errors.
>   You could try to install GTK2 engine, to see if that gets your theme working.
>   By [@LnxSlck](https://askubuntu.com/users/49189/lnxslck)

Just download and install GTK+2.0 from launchpad, [click here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/2.24.6-0ubuntu5).

And for others Ubuntu versions, [click here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0).